# How to stream a log files in a Windows Box to S3 in real time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

In AWS, How to stream a log files in a Windows Box to S3 in real time?

Thought of having a Kinesis Firehose configured to a S3 but later realized there is no Windows Agent for Kenesis.

But I feel we can acheive the same using API Calls. Any pointer or code examples will help us.

Language : .NET /
Platform : Windows 2012 R2 Server

This is a product from SAP, It is using Log4Net. Is there any example on how to configure the xml?

Note : Currently we are using aws sync command to push log files to S3 uisng a scheduled task (which runs every minute). I feel there should be a better way to implement this schenario.

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: This question doesn't provide enough information for an answer. For example, what language/platform are you using? I'm assuming .Net, and if you're also using Log4Net, [these Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=log4net+write+to+kinesis) might help you (I can't speak to the quality of the solutions, not having used them).

Comment: Still not enough information. Are you using Log4Net? Writing directly to the console? Something else?

Comment: If you do want to implement it yourself, the source code for the AWS agent is [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent).